# A simple algebra question involving a sum of a series

Tags: calculus

I'm sorry if the question is silly, but I wondered if the next equation is right:

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {2^{n-k}}k = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {2^k}$$

And if not, is there a way to represent it without the sum $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {2^{n-k}}k$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $(\sum_{k = 1}^n k)(\sum_{k = 1}^n {2^k})$ for the RHS?

Comment: Nope.  Let $n=1$ to see a counter-example.

Comment: Try it with $n = 3$ for example... You will immediately know it is not correct.

Comment: Yea..I'm trying to find a way to represent it without the sum..:(

Comment: nope, but $\sum_\limits {k=1}^n 2^{n-k}k = 2^n \sum_\limits {k=1}^n \frac {k}{2^k}$

Comment: Note that for $x\neq 1$ one has $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ (*this is the standard geometric series*).  Now... what happens if you derive both sides of that with respect to $x$ and then multiply the result by $x$?  You will have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n kx^k = \dots$ (*I leave it to you to calculate the right hand side*).  Using $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and the rearrangement that Doug suggested, you will arrive at a closed form expression for your series.

Comment: Thank you and sorry again, but how can I find a closed form expression of the one that Doug M suggested?

Comment: I already gave you the method... Take the closed form of the geometric series, derive both sides with respect to $x$ and then multiply both sides with respect to $x$.  You have access to tools from calculus, yes?  You should know how to derive $\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ with respect to $x$... use your quotient rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first note that left-hand side and right-hand side of the equation are different.

> The LHS is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^nk\sum_{k=1}^n2^k&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n2^k\right)\\
> &=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)(2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^n)
> \end{align*}
>   whereas the RHS is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{n-k}k=1\cdot 2^{n-1}+2\cdot 2^{n-2}+3\cdot 2^{n-3}+\cdots+n\cdot 2^0
> \end{align*}
>   which are quite different, already when $n=1$.

We can derive a closed formula as follows:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^nk2^{n-k}&=2^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\frac{1}{2^k}\right)=2^n\left.\left(\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=2^n\left.\left(x\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\tag{1}\\
> &=2^{n-1}\left.\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^nx^k\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\tag{2}\\
> &=2^{n-1}\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\tag{3}\\
> &=2^{n-1}\left.\left(\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(1-x)^2}\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\tag{4}\\
> &=2^{n+1}-n-2\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the sum as series in $x$ evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and factor out $x$ to prepare it for differentiation.
- In (2) we write the sum as derivative of a finite geometric series in $x$ and evaluated the single factor $x$ left from the sum already at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
- In (3) we apply the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (4) we differentiate the expression.
- In (5) we finally evaluate the expression at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in order to get a closed formula.

*Note:* If this derivation is at the time too complicated, we could also *claim* the final result (5) and prove it using *[mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)*.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh Markus! Is there a way to leave you a personal message?

Comment: @Lola: You're welcome! If you like, you can send an email to mscheuer123@gmail.com. Regards,